# Does Smack work well in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, smack, google-talk

Does Smack function properly in Java EE?? I am having issues with presence.
I get the credentials from the login form via doPost method..I can able to successfully authenticate as well as connection.getRoster() also works.Next I want to show only users who are online so when I get the presence of user,presence object stores default value "unavailable" for all users even when they are available!!

The whole chat app works without flaw in a normal java class without any change..

```
            String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", userName);

    SmackAPIGtalkServlet gtalk = new SmackAPIGtalkServlet();

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
            "talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.login(userName, password);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(connection.isAuthenticated());
    boolean status = connection.isAuthenticated();
    if (status == true) {
        gtalk.displayOnlineBuddyList();
        response.sendRedirect("Roster.jsp");

    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("Failed.jsp");
    }
}

public void displayOnlineBuddyList() {
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        Presence presence = roster.getPresence(r.getUser());
        if (presence.getType() == Presence.Type.unavailable) {
            // System.out.println(user + "is offline");
            count1++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(name+user + "is online");
            count2++;
        }
    }
    roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
        // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String>
        // addresses) {}
        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
        }

        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
        }

        public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
            System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom()
                    + " " + presence);
        }

        @Override
        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

I am stuck with this and not able to get the code working with servlets..Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Yes smack works well for j2ee at least for me.

Comment: post the code. It has nothing to do with java-ee

Comment: @Jigar Joshi-Have edited my question..You can tak a look at it

Comment: @newbie: can you see any presence change in `presenceChanged(..)...` method? Does it prints presence changed after you login?

Comment: No I cant...The presenceChanged() is not working....I checked with toXML() its assigned "unavailable" for al users irrespective of the status or status change.On the whole the presence is not working at all

Comment: @newbie: are you subscribed to the user's presence? if not then you will not receive any update on presence of that user.

Comment: @Harry- you mean this rite?Presence.Type.SUBSCRIBE ?? Correct me if I am wrong but why should I again subscribe for their presence..All I am doing is connecting to Gtalk and retreving the already existing friends list?? Also the same code in java class works perfectly fine..I dont do any subscription there....

Comment: @newbie: Yes. If you are retrieving friend list from gtalk then they are already subscribed no need to do it again.

Comment: @Harry-yes I am retreving already existing friends whose presence is subscribed in gtalk... Any ideas where I am going wrong??

Comment: @newbie : I think before the presenceChanged method is called after sometime, you are redirected to Roster.jsp so you are getting the presence unavailable in jsp page.

Comment: @Ankit-I tried commenting the line and printing the online users in console...No success then also...Is there a different workaround specifically for servlets?

Comment: @Harry Joy- can you show me your code..Is it the same as above??

Comment: @newbie : No it should work. Just remove SetSASLAutheticationEnabled and also add the following line after you login **roster.setSubscriptionMode(SubscriptionMode.manual);**

Comment: @Ankit-But why should I again subscribe presence of users when they are already in gtalk..does subscribe mean that taking permission from the server to get the presence of users or from the users itself...Correct me if I amw wrong??

Comment: @newbie : you are right.

Comment: @newbie: try this: 1) make a class that implements RosterListener. 2) add that as a rosterListener in roster. 3) Check that you can get presence event there or not. That class should be simple java class not a servlet.

Comment: @Harry Joy -I can give it a try to see if this works there..The requirement is to capture in servlets...

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the **RosterListener** interface in which you have to override the **presenceChanged** method in that you can get the presence of the users.

It works for me.

When you are getting the rosters of GTalk all will have status as unavailable.

But after sometime their presence changes and the presence can be get from the presenceChanged method in the RosterListner but for that you have to implement the RosterListener's presenceChnaged method.

And ya it works well in Java EE, Android as well as WAP.

Comment: @newbie : initially you will get unavailable for all users so just go through the above answer I have posted and your code will work.

Comment: @Ankit-I am using RosterListener in the code above...The whole presence does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Will Smack work inside of Java EE, yes and no.
Smack will work inside of a web container, but since it creates its own threads it will NOT work inside of an EJB container.  So it will work depending on where you are running it.

To understand some of your issues, you have to understand that the lifecycle of your objects in a servlet is tied to the request/response cycle of each request.  This is not the same as a standard java app where the objects will typically live as long as you need them to, since you control their lifecycle.

For example, in the code you have shown, you create the connection for each request (I assume, since not all the code is shown).  Therefore registering listeners against that connection will be pointless since it will pass out of scope as soon as you leave the method, and eventually get garbage collected.  You will have to maintain the connections outside of the scope of the servlet requests for this to work, otherwise you will be opening and closing connections for each request.

XMPP is completely asynchronous by nature whereas servlet requests are synchronous.  You have to put some effort in to making them work together, so don't expect code that works in a standalone app to simply work in this environment.

Comment: @Robin..can you suggest a workaround for this??What can be done??

Answer (score -2):

Does Smack function properly in Java EE?? I am having issues with presence. I get the credentials from the login form via doPost method..I can able to successfully authenticate as well as connection.getRoster() also works.Next I want to show only users who are online so when I get the presence of user,presence object stores default value "unavailable" for all users even when they are available!! here my code

```
<%
 Roster rst = roster;
 rst.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
public void entriesAdded(final Collection args) {}

public void entriesDeleted(final Collection<String> addresses) {}

public void entriesUpdated(final Collection<String> addresses) {}

public void presenceChanged(final Presence presence) {
    final Presence prsence1 = presence;
    prsenceChanged(prsence1);
    if (prsence1.isAvailable()) {
        System.out.println("Is Available: " + presence.isAvailable());
    } 


}
});

 %> 



<%!void prsenceChanged(Presence presence){ if(null != presence){%>
<script language="javascript"> 
    alert("hai");   

</script>
```